# mongodb's ensureIndex doesn't work accurately

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

mongodb version: osx-x86_64-2.4.5

I have a collection of users with geolocation data in the following form:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : "24128f74-3e47-4f02-8188-37779f3eca3c",
        "geolocation" : {
            "lat" : 55.5884705,
            "lng" : 13.0111425
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : "65db4271-8eff-4619-95fb-08135cbccb8f",
        "geolocation" : {
            "lat" : 55.58934530000001,
            "lng" : 13.0066488
        },
        "email" : "stephan3@stephan3.com"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "74d17da5-af4c-4386-9efa-9817f11b64f9",
        "geolocation" : {
            "lat" : 55.58934530000001,
            "lng" : 13.0066488
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : "d0378d09-1f69-4e01-8602-b4805466a029",
        "geolocation" : {
            "lat" : 55.590957,
            "lng" : 13.001412
        }
    }
]
```

As I don't want to migrate any production data, I created an index to be able to use geospatial queries such as *$geoWithin* as documented here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2dsphere-index/:

```
db.user.ensureIndex({ geolocation : '2d'})
```

If I query the *user* collection like in the following way, I get an empty array back

```
db.user.find({ geolocation: {
   $geoWithin : {
      $center : [ [ 13.0111425,55.5884705 ], 1 ]
   }
}});
```

Note that this is the exact location as user 24128f74-3e47-4f02-8188-37779f3eca3c, so at least she should be returned.

When I convert the users' geolocation property into the [ long, lat ] format, so a user entry looks like the following, and then apply the same query again, I get all users, also the ones that are further away.

```
[
{
    "_id" : "24128f74-3e47-4f02-8188-37779f3eca3c",
    "geolocation" : [
        13.0111425,
        55.5884705
    ]
}, 
    ...
]
```

Do you have an idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: The second one is the right format for the cordinates, and all your point at least those which are listed here are in the 1 radius circle what you defined in your query. So are you sure that some points are out? While it is sure that in the first case the format is the problem.